# Using onBackPressed with Cordova backbutton

Tags: javascript, java, android, jquery, cordova

I asked a similar question before but I'm hoping with additional information and with what I learnt from the previous question I might be able to solve my issue.
I need to be able to use the back button on my Android phone. At the moment I have the Cordova backbutton implemented which caused the application to go back 2 pages per click.

I should also mention that my app is build around JavaScript, HTML and CSS with very minimal Java as you will see below.

Backbutton JS code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); 

function onDeviceReady() {
//alert ('123');
document.addEventListener('backbutton', onBackKeyDown, false);
}

function onBackKeyDown()
{
    currentPage = $.mobile.activePage.attr('id');
    if(currentPage == "createUser"){
        $.mobile.changePage("#logIn");
        alert("Return To Login Page");
    }

    if(currentPage == "cardDetails"){
        $.mobile.changePage("#createUser");
        alert("Return to Create User");
    }
    if(currentPage == "mainMenu"){
        $.mobile.changePage("#logIn");
        alert("Return To Log In");
    }
    if(currentPage == "locationPage"){
        $.mobile.changePage("#mainMenu");
        alert("Return To Main Menu");
        $("#pId").empty();
    }
    if(currentPage == "editUserPage")
    {
        $.mobile.changePage("#mainMenu");
        alert("Return To Main Menu");
        $("#trId").empty();
    }
    if(currentPage == "editCardDetailsPage")
    {
        $.mobile.changePage("#editUserPage");
        alert("Return To Edit User");
    }
}
```

I was told to implement a onBackPressed function inside my java file. I'm not very experienced in Java but with a bit of help I was able to figure out where the code goes

Java code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

public class FnBApp extends DroidGap {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       //Log.d("CDA", "onBackPressed Called");
       //if super.getUrl shows a specific page:
       if() {
           super.loadUrl("file://android_asset/www/index.html#login");
       };
    }
}
```

Now I'm not sure what I should put in the if statement in the Java file I've tried `WebView`, `AppView` and a few other things to no avail and from what I can see using Java will only change the page which if that is all I wanted to do I wouldn't need to edit the back button functions but as I have placed in the backbutton js code, I also need to run some DOM functions as well.

Is there a way to be able to run the DOM functions in conjunction with the Java

If any more clarification is needed let me know.

John

Comment: I don't really understand why you think you need Java to implement that. It seems that with the JS code, it is already working. When the backbutton is pressed it goes to the page that you want with $.mobile.changePage().

Comment: When I press the back button it goes back 2 pages. So say the currentPage was cardDetails, if I hit the back button it changes the page to createUser and then changes the page to logIn

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that the backbutton fires two events because it goes back to page. What you need to do in JavaScript is to stop the event propagation.
So, you need to get the event on the `onBackKeyDown` and stop propagation with  `event.preventDefault();`. You don't need Java.

```
function onBackKeyDown(event)
{
    currentPage = $.mobile.activePage.attr('id');
    if(currentPage == "createUser"){
        $.mobile.changePage("#logIn");
        alert("Return To Login Page");
    }

    if(currentPage == "cardDetails"){
        $.mobile.changePage("#createUser");
        alert("Return to Create User");
    }
    if(currentPage == "mainMenu"){
        $.mobile.changePage("#logIn");
        alert("Return To Log In");
    }
    if(currentPage == "locationPage"){
        $.mobile.changePage("#mainMenu");
        alert("Return To Main Menu");
        $("#pId").empty();
    }
    if(currentPage == "editUserPage")
    {
        $.mobile.changePage("#mainMenu");
        alert("Return To Main Menu");
        $("#trId").empty();
    }
    if(currentPage == "editCardDetailsPage")
    {
        $.mobile.changePage("#editUserPage");
        alert("Return To Edit User");
    }
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: It still goes back 2 pages. Not sure if this has anything to do with it but in the onDeviceReady function I uncommented the alert and for some reason it fires 3 times when I load the app

Comment: Does your other alerts are displayed like `alert("Return To Edit User");``? Try also to return false in this function.

Comment: The other alerts just show once, tried to adding false with preventDefault, on it's own, in the functions themselves. Nothing worked. But It seems like both alerts trigger before the page changes at all.